# App crashes in the thread named com.apple.CFURLCACHE_work_queue

Tags: ios

My app crashed in the thread named com.apple.CFURLCACHE_work_queue and the crash logs doesn't seem to provide any clues for me to find a bug or mistake =(

```
Thread 10 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CFURLCACHE_work_queue
Thread 10 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32e93350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b04011e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b07c96e abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x343ebd4a abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x343e8ff4 default_terminate() + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3559fa74 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x343e9078 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x343e9110 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x343ea50e __cxa_throw + 118
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3559f9ba objc_exception_throw + 90
10  Foundation                      0x34d42b60 _NSOutOfMemoryErrorHandler + 56
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3725130a __CFDataHandleOutOfMemory + 90
12  CoreFoundation                  0x37251458 __CFDataGrow + 288
13  CoreFoundation                  0x371d6134 CFDataReplaceBytes + 360
14  CoreFoundation                  0x371e3a9a CFDataAppendBytes + 82
15  CFNetwork                       0x33150438 CopyAllDataFromDataArray(__CFArray const*) + 104
16  CFNetwork                       0x331509ae __CFURLCache::ExecuteSQLInsert(_CFCachedURLResponse const*, __CFString const*, _CFURLRequest const*) + 370
17  CFNetwork                       0x3314ec62 __CFURLCache::AddCachedResponseForRequest(__CFURLCacheNode*, _CFCachedURLResponse const*, _CFURLRequest const*) + 58
18  CFNetwork                       0x3314eab8 __CFURLCache::ProcessCacheTasks0(bool) + 140
19  CFNetwork                       0x3314ea1c __CFURLCache::ProcessCacheTasks(bool) + 32
20  CFNetwork                       0x3314e8f0 __CFURLCache::_CFURLCacheTimerCallback0() + 280
21  CFNetwork                       0x3314e7c8 __CFURLCache::_CFURLCacheTimerCallback(void*) + 28
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x35f86134 _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 248
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x35f83e8e _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 78
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x35f83dbc _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 36
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x35f8491a _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 182
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x35f84abc _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
27  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b017a0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
28  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b0178a0 start_wqthread + 4
```

any idea or clue of why this happens?
I guess it has something to do with NSURLCache, but I don't manipulate or even create that object in my app.

I'm using Xcode 4.5 GM - I know it's not publicly released yet - and AFNetworking 1.0RC3 for network communication and downloading image data

Comment: Did you find solution for this crash?

Comment: @pilot34 sorry. it's quite a long time ago and I don't remember whether I've found a solution or not. bad memory. :(

Answer (score 0):

From the look of things in numbers 10 and 11, it ran out of memory and threw an exception, maybe as part of some kind of assertion.

You will probably find exception information in the console log for the device. If you can connect your device to your Mac, you can access this data in Xcode.  Devices don't keep much console data, so it is best to get the log very soon after encountering the error.